# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when machine time format is changed.

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Date string in format `dd/MM/yyyy` I am string to get this string in 'yyyyMMdd' 
So I tried :

```
todate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txttdate.Text).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

and it worked fine when my local machine time was in format `dd/MM/yyyy` but then when I change the system time format it stops working it gives me error

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

How do solve this problem? I need to convert `dd/MM/yyyy` string to `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: I will accept answers in c# or vb both since there are plenty of converters available online ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime` and specify the pattern and `InvariantCulture` as format provider:

```
var todate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(@"05/12/2013", @"dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

It should prevent your code from failure on different culture settings.

Comment: Yup, its working now. btw can you please elaborate on `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None` so that I understand when to use it and not just use it blindly every time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ParseExact` and specifiy `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
DateTime todate1;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txttdate.Text, new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out todate1)) {
    string yourNewFormat = todate1.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
}
else {
    // it failed
}
```

Using `TryParseExact` allows you to recover from potentially invalid dates being provided.

Comment: Why init to `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: No reason.. typed quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my web application, tried many things like above but nothing helped me. But when I added globalization tag in my config file it worked like a charm.

```
    <system.web>
      <globalization requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
    </system.web>
```

change culture to US or IN or whatever u want.